# Advice on how to implement url source encryption with key-pair-id

Tags: url, encryption, key-pair

can someone shed a light on how to do encryption to get url like this one?
or suggest usefull links to look into/keywords to search for?

```
src:  url(/v2/eot?3Ah8HC7Qb48S3EOXjXedg8ZHeKl8Q4VZMAB&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cCo6Ly8qL3YyL2VvdD8zQWg4SEM3UWI0OFMzRU9YalhlZGc4WkhlS2w4UTRWWk1BQiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTQyODQ1MTIwMH19fV19&Signature=kgbgaLMwIUll5fl1N0Y5VNb9KGNnbySP48nd1snzdnWAbxPPao2wlvZDlXfWtO69dlPGhfE3HVk25CI0skIpL4jWofqWOlFx4jPP~vVWl7z3hcKrg6Z5vjpSlYCZxHMlQkbotJN3sd5VeID6WeTEe1j6KIk2sLtLgjFdlpgKGpGXNgare7AmrMHpRHdYWr-PCMpHMEbTyhxXVvkXjiS1RDk7OuwrjgASEEPYqcsQHzGjLzn1PcMWX78D~Ri-2nK0RkufEKMq8SanRcGfV7W7AWuXKWeA8gVNJfWjpA~1oFHocvT~cNTUnBnzKQL7sQZDRWiYsUIu3ht26CJ-9y6iNA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJN6QFZEE4BZCL6XQ);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is taken form a css file which appends `http://easy.myfonts.net/`to the beginning of the string to form an url request. The string isn't actually encrypted. Thus, your example redirects to

```
 http://easy.myfonts.net/v2/eot?3Ah8HC7Qb48S3EOXjXedg8ZHeKl8Q4VZMAB&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cCo6Ly8qL3YyL2VvdD8zQWg4SEM3UWI0OFMzRU9YalhlZGc4WkhlS2w4UTRWWk1BQiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTQyODQ1MTIwMH19fV19&Signature=kgbgaLMwIUll5fl1N0Y5VNb9KGNnbySP48nd1snzdnWAbxPPao2wlvZDlXfWtO69dlPGhfE3HVk25CI0skIpL4jWofqWOlFx4jPP~vVWl7z3hcKrg6Z5vjpSlYCZxHMlQkbotJN3sd5VeID6WeTEe1j6KIk2sLtLgjFdlpgKGpGXNgare7AmrMHpRHdYWr-PCMpHMEbTyhxXVvkXjiS1RDk7OuwrjgASEEPYqcsQHzGjLzn1PcMWX78D~Ri-2nK0RkufEKMq8SanRcGfV7W7AWuXKWeA8gVNJfWjpA~1oFHocvT~cNTUnBnzKQL7sQZDRWiYsUIu3ht26CJ-9y6iNA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJN6QFZEE4BZCL6XQ
```

The hostname maps to a CloudFront ip, so I assume the signed url is generated by Amazon CloudFront to access the hosted content. [Here's an article to create signed URLs with Amazon AWS.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html)

Comment: also, @ilian000 can you explain how you traced the website url, based on css source above?

Comment: @unkind I searched for the Key-Pair-Id in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=APKAJN6QFZEE4BZCL6XQ), which returned me several results containing the same url.